# Using HDD as an input device for Arduino

Tags: arduino, input, interface, hacking, hard-drive

I'm wondering if is it possible to use an **old HDD** as an **input device** that would feed some kind of **data to Arduino**.

If you **manually positioned** the head and platter (the disk is not spinning, so it would remain in one place)- would it be possible to get the coordinates (track: XXX, sector: YYY) of the reading head to arduino? Is it possible to get any kind of (reproducable) output that way?

If yes - what should I study, read or know about? How to get started?
If no - any ideas how could I use some other computer hardware in a similar manner?

The idea is to make an interactive installation, where touching "the guts of old hardware" (spinning the platter and moving the head manually) would result in different LED colors - like mapping disk to a color wheel or sth like this.

Comment: Of course not! How do you expect the disk to know in which position you have rotated it **manually**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sense rotation using the coils from the HDD motor, but it would be much simpler to remove it and stick a rotary encoder to the drive's shaft.

Now, for the head... as said above it uses information on the spinning disk to sense its position, so it won't work. You could stick a potentiometer in there, or a hall sensor using the magnets to determine the head position. That would work.

Comment: Aah great ideas, will definitely dive into theese options! :D 

So maybe I should think more about using mechanical parts with my own electronic components + arduino, rather than using original HDD circuitry...

Comment: Yeah, if it's for an art project, who cares about the implementation details as long as it does what you want. Keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 2):

No. Disk drives don't work that way. The location data (track and sector numbers) are recorded on the disk itself, and the heads are positioned by a servomechanism that uses that data as feedback. The disk has to be spinning for that to work.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What about if you only moved the head around, while the disk is spinning?

Comment: Well, assuming the heads don't crash, wiping out all of the data, the servo would fight you, trying to keep the heads on the track that the controller has selected.